# Limited Usage Permission field in License Permission system table

Tags: licensing, navision

I've created a new page of type List from wizard to show all the fields **License Permission (2000000043)** system table in **NAV 2015**.

This field is populated only in the records where **Object Type** is **LimitedUsageTableData** and it's an option with the following 
**Option Strings = , Included, Excluded, Optional**

I haven't found an official documentation that explain the meaning of the different values and how to change them (The License Permission table is read-only).

I think this might be related to the limits a user with Limited User license can have.

Just for an example, the table Service Order Allocation 5950 has Limited Usage Permission = Optional. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limited users licensing is explained in detail in the document named "Microsoft Dynamics NAV Licensing Guide". You can download the latest version from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54248

In short, limited users are allowed to read any table and write to any 3 tables only. You do not need to specify which 3 tables would that be, NAV just counts database writes until there will be an attempt to write to 4th table.

In addition to this rule, there are granted tables which are not counted when you write to them, and there are restricted tables you can never write to.

**Limited Usage Permission = Included** - means that table is granted and does not count towards maximum of 3.

**Limited Usage Permission = Excluded** - means that table is restricted to write (e.g. G/L Entry)

**Limited Usage Permission = Optional** - means all the rest

You are not able to change these values as they are changed by Microsoft only and are part of a license. But partners are able to elect some of the tables in their ranges to be "Included" (which has to be approved by Microsoft).